Fixing Folium Map Size in PDF using pdfkit in Python
I'm working on a Python project where I need to generate a PDF document from an HTML page that includes a Folium map. The map is created and saved as an HTML file using Folium, and then I'm trying to convert this HTML into a PDF using pdfkit. However, I'm struggling with setting a fixed size for the map in the resulting PDF file. The map either stretches or shrinks, not adhering to the dimensions I intend to set.
Here's the code snippet I'm working with:
import folium
import pdfkit

# Create a Folium map centered at a specific location
map = folium.Map(location=[48.856614, 2.352222])

# Add a marker to the map
folium.Marker([48.856614, 2.352222]).add_to(map)

# Save the map as an HTML file
map.save('map.html')

# Attempt to convert the HTML map to a PDF file
pdfkit.from_file("map.html", "sample_file.pdf")

Issue:
I got this:

Objective:
I want to define the map's size in the PDF to be, for example, 800x600 pixels. However, there seems to be no direct way to specify the dimensions of the map in the PDF output. The map does not maintain the size I have in mind when viewed in the PDF.
Question:
How can I ensure that the map in the PDF maintains a fixed size (e.g., 800x600 pixels)? Is there a way to directly control the map's dimensions in the PDF output using pdfkit, or do I need to manipulate the HTML/CSS in some specific way before conversion?
Thank you for your assistance!
